# Pandas Frequency of Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing some work in pandas and I am trying to find certain values from the dataset. I am looking for the mode and mode frequency of a certain column.

I have gotten the mode using `df.col1.mode()`, this works fine and returns the mode (eg Male). Now I am having trouble getting the frequency of this value in the column. I know I can get the frequency of all the values in the column using `df.col1.value_counts()`

I tried using `df.col1.value_counts()['Male']` to try get the number of times this occurs but I get an error saying `KeyError: 'Male'`

Is this the right way to find the number of times a certain value appears in a column?

Comment: That would mean there is no 'Male' in column 'col1'. So that is a good way, but only works if you are certain this value occurs in the column.

Comment: Yes that's the right way and I am unable to replicate your issue. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print df

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

df.groupby('A').size()/df['A'].count()

A
1    0.333333
4    0.333333
7    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: But how do I just get the results for the value that occurs the most, not the values for all them

Answer (score 0):

One problem that you will encounter is having multiple items in mode, so that you don't have a one-to-one mapping.  As a way around this, you can use a dictionary comprehension to get the mode of each.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Shemale'], 
                   'State': ['CA', 'OR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'NY']})

modes = df.gender.mode()
>>> {item: len(df.gender[df.gender.isin(modes[modes == item])]) for item in modes}
{'Female': 2, 'Male': 2}
```